# submitting a form in a modal with ajax using laravel

Tags: ajax, forms, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload both text and files through a form loaded inside a modal and submit it using ajax (I'm using Laravel 5.2) and I can't figure out why it doesn’t working. I have tried many solutions found here and through a search engine.

**A simple form (this form is loaded in a modal)**

```
<form id="registerForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">


<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="pwd">Choose File</label>
<div class="col-md-6"> 
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileProfPic" name="prof_pic">
</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="registerButtonModal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register</button>
</form>
```

**.js**

```
$("#registerButtonModal").click(function(){
    $('#registerForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#registerForm')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'register',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            }
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

        });
        });
});
```

**route**

```
 Route::post('register',[
        'uses' => 'AdminController@postRegister',
        'as' => 'postRegister']);
```

**controller //just trying to make it work**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: "doesnt working" not helping us understand your problem

Comment: well if i know whats cause the problem i would tell, but in this case my controller simply doesnt get called .

Comment: use chrome, press f12 switch to network tab, submit the form, look at the error you get

Comment: Chances are it's a CORS error. Please check your browsers development console log and revert

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to the fact your AJAX should be returning a JSON response with your controller.

Try the following:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => 'success']);
    }
```

With the above you will now have access to the object within your view.

Also, remember to pass your CSRF token in your AJAX. I usually add this in my view when i use AJAX and I pass that variable to data as seen below:

```
<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
</script>

$.ajax({
        url: 'register',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {variable1: variable1, variable2: variable2, _token: token},,
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    });
```